# red dot remains with drm-free imageresizer

Tags: nuget, licensing, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

So I have installed the Imageresizer with the Diskcache plugin from the `elite nuget`. I have restarted the `apppool` by touching the `web.config`. I cleared the `imagecache` folder and browser cache. But the red dot remains on the image. 
Also in the diagnostics it says no license is installed. How can i verify that it downloads the nuget package from the `elite nuget`?

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      new.kohleroptik.ch  29.06.2016 08:58:15

1 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(Error):   No license found for domain new.kohleroptik.ch - features installed: R4Performance or R4DiskCache


Assembly use report: 


You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.


----------------

License keys

You do not have any license keys installed.

----------------



Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]

Configuration:

<resizer>
<diskCache dir="~/Media.Cache" />
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
</plugins>
</resizer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://twitter.com/nathanaeljones/status/748158220074549248

Machine wide NuGet cache got me. New bug in NuGet.
Clear it, and re download from MyGet to get the DRM free binaries.

```
nuget locals -clear all
```

**Edit**

I had this issue again. I had to scan my pc for any imageresizer dll.
They were everywhere.

- AppData
- ASP.Net Cache
- Microsoft Cache
- NuGet Cache etc.